# See (Elsewhere) in the Index; What am I Doing Wrong?

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, makeindex, idxlayout

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\begin{document}
\Large
    
Some words.\index{HEADING@\textbf{\textit{HEADING}}! |see{\textbf{SOME PLACE ELSE IN THE INDEX}}}
               
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: Why is there a leading comma on the line after the heading; and how may I eliminate it?
Is my code correct?

Thank you.

Comment: well mostly as you are straining the concept of index here, `\index` is intended to make index entries not headings so the normal use would end up with `Heading, see other thing`, although as in your previous question if you want to eat the comma you can replace @\textbf{  by a custtom command with an extra argument that gobbles it or use a custom makeindex style that does not use a comma here.

Comment: @David Carlisle I thought, perhaps, there might be a natural way of avoiding the comma using `|see` instead of going the "gobble" route.

Comment: but you are already abusing the syntax with the null entry after `!` so indexing a space the whole construct is not really an index entry at all.

Comment: @David Carlisle How? What should the syntax be then in order to have the `see` appear on the second line with the subsequent content in bold? Hence, the title---"What am I doing wrong?"

Comment: `\index{a!b}` is designed to index `b` as a sub entry under `a`  so in your case you are indexing space under a sub entry of heading, then using `@` to force it to not look like an entry at all but as a note under a heading.

Comment: @David Carlisle O.K. Thank you.